# how to satisfy inner class in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, rest-api

```
global class ResultClass{
        public String id;
        public Boolean success;
        public List<String> errors;
        public ResultClass(String id, Boolean status, List<Database.error> errList){
            this.id = id;
            success = status;
            errors = new List<String>();
            for(Database.error err :errList){
                errors.add(err.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }``
```

i have this code and i want to create the constructor forsatisfy thiss method but i dont know how to pass the argument for List errList this, i tried to create list but it is still giving error constructor not defined.

```
List<string> errorlist = new List<string>();
        errorlist.add('error1');
        errorlist.add('error2');
        schemaDataAPI.ResultClass schemaresult = new schemaDataAPI.ResultClass('test',true,errorlist);
```

this is my code that i tried.

Comment: Where is SchemaDataAPI? Can you post your complete code? BTW the constructor you have defined takes a list of  `Database.Error` class as an input and you are passing a `List<String>`.

Comment: yes,this is my mistake. can you please tell  me how to pass the List<Database.error>?

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing the class do it in isolation and to directly answer your question:

> Use json to deserialize a list of database errors since it cannot be constructed.

So something like the following:

```
@IsTest
private class myExampleInnerTest_Test {
    private static string testErrorJSON = '[{"statusCode":"MISSING_ARGUMENT","message":"Id not specified in an update call","fields":[]}]';

    static testMethod void testBehavior() {

        Database.Error[] errList = (Database.Error[])json.deserialize(testErrorJSON,List<Database.Error>.class);

        myExampleInnerTest.ResultClass result = New myExampleInnerTest.ResultClass(
                null,
                false,
                errList
        );

        //Add your system asserts 
        System.assertEquals(false,result.success,'Success value of class was not set properly');
        System.assertEquals(false,result.errors.isEmpty(),'The error list was empty in the inner class');
        System.assertEquals(errList[0].getMessage(),result.errors[0],'The error message was not as expected');
        System.assertEquals(null,result.id,'The Id was not null when null was used during instantiation');

    }
}
```

Make several test methods to validate the different scenarios. For example if a null error list is passed in your test will fail. You will want to adjust your inner class to handle to that test passes.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong input as parameter, You need to pass `List<Database.Error>` as input rather than `List<String>`.

now if you want to create records of `Database.error` class you would need to insert records of some object which have some sort of validation on them.

Suppose on Contact there is a **validation** that **LastName should not be 'Test'**. So in your test class **create some records of Contact. One or more records should have LastName as 'Test'**.

Now insert the List using `Database.insert`.

```
List<Database.SaveResult> results  = Database.Insert(con_list); 
List<Database.Error> errors = new List<Database.Error>();
for(Database.SaveResult dsr : results){
if(!dsr.isSuccess()){
   for(Database.Error err : dsr.getErrors()){
      errors.add(err);
   }
}
}
```

This way you can get the `Database.Error` records. This is just an example, you can be more creative in "throwing the Exception" and get the records of `Database.Error` class

Comment: Easiest way to do it without any extra validation -- do Insert twice :)

Comment: @kurunve - Nah, easiest way to get exactly what you want when just testing the class is to use JSON deserialization.